# SQL Server Replication Job Error: Message: Command Text: SELECT TOP 1 0 FROM [dbo].[tablename] WITH (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK)

Tags: sql-server-2016, database-administration

SQL Snapshot replication is failing due to this message:

Message: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. 
Command Text: SELECT TOP 1 0 FROM [dbo].[tablename] WITH (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK)

I'm not quite sure where to start finding this issue.  I've searched Google and SO, I didn't find anything that helps me get to the bottom of this.  Is this just an issue with a table either being locked or not locked when it should be?

Questions/Answers:

- What part of the process fails, creating a snapshot or the log reader?  *The error is in creating the snapshot.*
- Is the error in the replication monitor and is the source the publisher or subscriber?  *The error is in the replication monitor and it is the publisher.*

**Desired Result:**

- No error, snapshot replication not timing out.

Thank you.

Comment: What part of the process fails, creating a snapshot or the log reader? Is the error in the replication monitor and is the source the publisher or subscriber? The more info you can add the better.

Comment: @RossBush, I edited the question to answer your questions.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new snapshot?

Comment: Btw, I found this, it could be related --> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1253109a-a6df-4829-8a82-8c2809901b75/replication-issue

Comment: A reboot of the server seemed to have fixed the issue.  I didn't reboot it as someone more familiar with the situation took care of it.